# Charge density and space inversion

Tags: symmetry, charge

J. D. Jackson in his book Classical Electrodynamics on page 249 ff. discusses the behaviour of electromagnetic quantities under space inversion (parity operation) and time reversal. 
He remarks:

> It is an experimental fact that electrical charge is invariant under Galilean and Lorentz transformation and is a scalar under rotations. It is natural, convenient, and permissible to assume that charge us a scalar under spatial inversion and even under time reversal. [...] With charge a true scalar under all three transformations, charge density $\rho$ is also a true scalar.

My question is about the relationship $\rho = Q /\Delta V$. Here $Q$ is charge and $V$ is volume. Volume behaves like a pseudoscalar under space inversion, e.g. in view of the relation $V = \vec{x} \cdot (\vec{y} \times \vec{z})$. Therefore I would have expected charge density to be a pseudoscalar under the convention that charge is a true scalar.
Or the other way around, when $\rho$ is invariant, charge to be a pseudoscalar for space inversion. What am I missing?

Comment: Really looking forward to reading the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The volume is defined as $V=|\vec{x}\cdot (\vec{y}\times \vec{z})|$, to avoid negative volumes. So under space inversion, volume would remain invariant, which is physically desirable since it should still take up the same amount of space.

New:
I guess you could define V to be a pseudoscalar, but that might have consequences. For example, mass is something that should be positive (negative mass has bad implications), and so it follows that it should be positive under parity. In SR, E=mc^2, so by this relation, energy should also be invariant under parity. Energy density = E/V, so if we allow V to change under parity, then Energy Density should also change. But in EM, energy density is derived to be $U=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\textbf{E}^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\textbf{B}^2$, the RHS is manifestly positive.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that myself. However it would be an equally valid assumption to consider charge and volume to be pseudoscalars.